# new template is not displaying properly

Tags: theme, template, mysql

I just installed a new theme. why it's displaying like this :

and check here too :

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I checked the source of the page. CSS files are called  with this url `http://theme7.newtrendzonline.comskin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css`

It's missing the **/** add the end of the domain. Please add a slash behind your base URL in the magento backend.

If you are unable to login to the backend use the following query

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = CONCAT(`value`, '/') WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR `path` = 'web/secure/base_url'
```

Comment: Hi @Sander, Thanks a lot. please check the link : it's working.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Please specify your theme hear.

system->configuration->general->Design

[image]

with your theme package name.

Not right path:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The package name has nothing to do with the path, that's the base url

Comment: Hi @ravi , Thanks a lot for reply. I appreciate your help.